# Can Google Play Services use cookies in-app?

Tags: android, cookies, admob, google-play-services

For example, I wonder if all the ways to create banners to be used by AdMob can inject a JS library that can create temporal cookies in-app while the banner is showed.

On a website the answer would be yes (using AdSense) but I think the answer is no when is used in-app because everything is managed through the services of Google Play Services according to [Google privacy policy](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/), and because cookies does not make sense on native app when they can use *device Id* according to [AdMob publisher guidelines and policies](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860)

> Google may use the device ID from where the ad is serving to generate interest and demographic categories (for example, 'sports enthusiasts' or 'inferred age: 18-34'). These interest and demographic categories will be used to serve ads better targeted to the user. Additionally, your app's privacy policy may need to be updated to reflect the use of interest-based advertising served via the Admob SDK. Please take a moment to review your app's privacy policies and ensure that they are up-to-date. Because publisher sites and laws vary across countries, we're unable to suggest specific privacy policy language.

I have to inform to my lawyers if my app uses cookies and the only services I am using are from GPS (AdMob/Google Maps/Google Cloud Messaging) and I want to be sure about that.

Sorry because the question has not a programmatic solution but this portal is one of the most used in Android. But it is a doubt and nowadays more legal texts are being put on each app to provide information to users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you track the http requests that AdMob do? Idk, but looking for headers for cookie is a attempt to discover your issue.

Comment: @Wakim Requests used to appear on logcat one year ago but now I do not see any requests that AdMob does. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: 2@AlexBcn: @Wakim probably means tracing network traffic to the AdMob's backend, not the LogCat requests. But that traffic will most probably go through HTTPS, so nothing will be readable, unless you do some tricks, like establishing local HTTPS proxy (e.g. Fiddler) and set up your device to connect through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, AdMob can use cookies.

Thanks to *Haspemulator*'s answer I started to follow the steps of this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2013/04/03/configuring-fiddler-to-be-a-proxy-for-android-emulators.aspx)

With Fiddler I had problems with the certificate, frequently it was asking me to add the certificate to the emulator even after installing it successfully, moreover I was only able to see https traffic of the browser, but not the traffic in-app. The same happened using another program as Charles, I only saw the browser traffic.

At the end I could use WireShark to monitor the local interface through the emulator is connected.

After an hour aprox. 4 cookies have been used filtering messages with `http.cookie`

```
1 test_cookie=CheckForPermission
3 using Cookie: id=XXXXXXXXXX||t=XXXXXXXXXXXX|et=XXX|cs=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

All from googleads.g.doubleclick.net.

This is the result using the Google Play Services, if someone uses the old (and it will be deprecated next August) 6.4.1 AdMob jar then Android Logcat shows similar requests as:

```
adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script>
<script>AFMA_buildAdURL    ({"preqs":2,"session_id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX","seq_num":"3","slotname":
"ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX\/XXXXXXXXXXXX", [...] "app_name":"1.android.com.myapp" [...] "isu":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" [...]</   script></head><body></body></html>
```

---

```
Received ad url: 
<url: "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=2&session_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX [...]app_name=1.android.com.myapp-VBbz2W5IoCKQHbsWJ4zXkdfm0kCzRThLrJysDmUGFUpRyBnkMNvT-Zr_dnfApKwnIOA
&client=ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX [...]type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null"     activationOverlayUrl: "null" useWebViewLoadUrl: "false">
```

So I guess it uses cookies due to googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/

Answer (score 2):

You might try to trace HTTP(S) traffic of your app that goes to AdMob. There you'll be able to see if server sets some kind of cookie HTTP header. Since this traffic most probably is going to be HTTPS-encrypted, you should use some tool like [Fiddler](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/decrypthttps/) to decrypt it. You'll have to configure your Android phone to use the machine where Fiddler is running as a proxy, then run your app, filter HTTPS traffic to AdMob and check its headers.

If you need help on some of the aforementioned topics, I guess it would be a separate questions, but I'm happy to help with them as well.

Comment: Thanks! It is too much for a comment so I describe what I have done on other answer.